# GPGPUsim PTX extraction

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

Just as the title says, I'm learning how to use the GPGPUsim. And when I read the "PTX extraction" section of the manual, I found that it says ***"In CUDA version 4.0 and later, the fat cubin file used to extract the ptx and sass is not available any more."*** which makes me confused. How to understand this, what happened in CUDA version 4.0 and later.
Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [CUDA 4.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-40) was released (in 2011!), the device toolchain was switched to a fully [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20the%20Executable%20and,shared%20libraries%2C%20and%20core%20dumps.) based object model. Prior to that, a plain text file with encoded binary sections for emitted SASS code and plain text for PTX was used. As a result, to extract PTX or SASS from an ELF CUDA object requires a utility [cuobjdump](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html) to access the requisite code.

Thus the pre/post CUDA 4.0 distinction.